# center a number within an image (rails)

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I would like the number to be centered within the image im using. Currently the number only looks nice as a single digit but at triple digits it leaves the background image.

[image][image]

Ruby:

```
 <%= image_tag("chat-bubble-icon.png", id: "comment_bubble") %> 
 <%= micropost.comments.count %>
```

CSS:

```
#comment_bubble {
  margin-left: 18px;
  margin-right: -20px;
}
```

Solution is to remove the image tag and use css to set it as a background for the comment.count

Comment: How you will center three digit number in the image?? your image is small.

Comment: haha 200 fits perfectly just checked

Comment: ok.. then had a div which has this bubble applied as background. and then set text align center for the div. set the line height equal to the height of the div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this

```
.comment_count{
 background: bubble.png;
 height: 100px;
 line-height:100px;
 width: 100px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: I think you should have added the modified html too. `<div class="comment_count"><%= micropost.comments.count %></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing more of the CSS and the generated HTML.

However, you should be able to center the numbers using

`margin:0 auto;`

and removing

```
margin-left: 18px;
margin-right: -20px;
```

Comment: The margin-left is to move the image to where I want it. Since the number is on the right I used a negative right margin to slide it over the bubble. setting margin 0 auto doesn't center the text.

Comment: Ok.  Will need to see more of the HTML, CSS in order to figure it out.

Comment: Posting a fiddle might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#comment_bubble {
  margin: auto;
}
```